# ITransferProgress and tracking data from attachments in MailKit

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I asked similar question earlier: [How to check amount of sent/received data in MailKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120220/how-to-check-amount-of-sent-received-data-in-mailkit) but now I'm talking about something else.

I have class that implements `ITransferProgress` interface. In this class I'm tracking transfer data and calculate speed. In my `sendMessage` method I create class object and update speed in table every one second:

```
ITransferProgressClass progress = new ITransferProgressClass();
//some code
progress.startTimer();
progress.SpeedCell = myRow.Cells[3];
client.Send(message, cancellationToken, progress);
progress.stopTimer();
```

And it works very good. I want to do something like this in `downloadMessage` method:

```
ITransferProgressClass progress = new ITransferProgressClass();
//some code
progress.startTimer();
progress.SpeedCell = myRow.Cells[3];
readyMessages.Add(client.Inbox.GetMessage(readySubjects[list[i]].UniqueId, cancellationToken, progress));
progress.stopTimer();
```

But every timer tick I'm getting 0 value. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download progress ends when the message gets returned by `GetMessage()`, it doesn't get used when you iterate over the attachments in the loop after that method is called.

Comment: The ITransferProgress updates will include the entire size of the message including the attachments. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Program update? Great! I'll be waiting. Now I'm writting application in which I send and download a large number of attachments. Btw. Earlier I used other mail libraries but many things they were missing. MailKit has everything. MailKit is the best! Thank you!

Comment: No, I mean that the ITransferProgress.Report() methods are already called for the entire MimeMessage, which includes the attachments.

Comment: You get 0 progress reports for GetMessage()?

Comment: Yes, i.e. I don't have progress of the transfer in `Report` method. Neither 0.

Comment: I just tested it and I `Report (long, long)` is getting called. Are you sure your `Report(long, long)` method isn't getting called at all?

Comment: I try only with `Report(long)`. How to use second method?

Comment: `Report (long, long)` is called when the total number of bytes of the download is known (the second argument is the total size).